# Drupal migrations ":additional_field" missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration, field, commerce

In the Commerce KickStart, they have a few migrations but the one that im trying to replicate is CommerceKickstartBagsCases, which is creating products of type Bags_Cases. Everything is great but in my migration, for a term reference, i am not given this option of "field_color:additional_field"

```
Class CommerceKickstartBagsCases extends CommerceKickstartMigration {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct($arguments = array()) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->description = t('Import bags cases from CSV file.');
...
// Color.
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_color', 'color');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_color:additional_field', 'hexadecimal');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_color:create_term')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);
...

}
}
```

Basically, in my Destination object i see field_color and field_color:create_term but not the "field_color:additional_field" option.

Basically, i can map the field and create a color term if it doesnt exist, but i need the "field_color:additional_field" because, besides the term name, i want to also populate a field called color with some RGB codes.

I know i can create Term migrations separately, but i would like to create those terms from my products migration just like commerce kickstart is doing it.

My feeling is that im missing a module but i can not put my finger on it.

PS: i spent 2hrs googling for this stuff but there's not much stuff there...

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with my migration I've found that if you have a field with sub-fields then this indicates that this is an entity not just a field and I have had to migrate that separately as an entity migration (in your case Term Migration) the linked it back up with the parent entity.